# Is there a better way to simplify this IF statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, bc

Is there a better way to simplify this IF statement. I've been told there is no need of using bc here because this adds to both computational and maintenance complexity to large scripts. Is there a way to avoid the use of bc here:

```
if [ `bc -l <<< "$AUTO_INCREMENT_RATIO>=0.9"` -eq 1 ]
  then
     <DO SOMETHING HERE>
  fi
```

Thank you!

I was trying something like

```
if [ $AUTO_INCREMENT_RATIO>=0.9 -eq 1 ]; then <DO SOMETHING HERE>; fi
```

But I get an error 'integer expression expected'

Comment: If you were dealing with integers, there would be no need to use `bc`. However, `bash` doesn't understand floating-point values, so that advice does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with floating points is to not use them in the first place!

Reading the name of your variable, it's a ratio. If by any chance, this ratio is a ratio of *positive integers*, say `a/b`, then, instead of comparing `a/b` with `0.9`, compare `10*a` with `9*b`.

This might not be directly applicable in your case, but that's a good thing to remember. A lot of problems that seem to involve floats, in fact only involve rational numbers and hence can be solved (usually more efficiently) using integers only.